# When an SSD finally reach its end of life, can you still read its data?

Tags: ssd, data-recovery

For "end of life" I mean when some of the SSD cells won't erase anymore, and the S.O. starts complaining about write failures.

When this finally happens, will I still be able to safely copy all of the data without any errors?

And if I don't replace it soon, will it ever stop working? (for reads only)

Comment: You should be backing up *before* failure occurs. Waiting for a device to die, then backing up is too late. Don't forget, that is only *one* failure mode. You may have controller failure, or random ferret attacks making your SSD unusable as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, it's a bit of a myth that SSDs will wear out, especially for typical desktop use.
But anyway:

From [another](https://superuser.com/questions/345997/what-happens-when-an-ssd-wears-out) superuser question:

> In theory, it is possible to read data [even after all program/erase
>   (p/e) cycles have been used up](http://thessdguy.com/what-happens-when-ssds-fail/). In fact, the [JEDEC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JEDEC) specifies
>   that data on consumer-grade SSDs should be readable for [one year
>   after all p/e cycles have been exhausted](http://www.anandtech.com/show/4902/intel-ssd-710-200gb-review/2). So the likelihood of
>   losing data due to the drive reaching the end of its lifetime is
>   small; it's more likely that you'll have replaced or upgraded your
>   system by then.

And [here](http://thessdguy.com/what-happens-when-ssds-fail/):

> Second, when an SSD is allowed to run right to the end of its useful life, most controllers put the SSD into a **“Read-Only” state** that allows the operator to remove the SSD, copy its contents onto another device, then re-start operations in the shortest amount of time.

So you can't write on it, but you will be able to copy its contents to your next SSD/HDD(for a reasonable amount of time).

Comment: Thanks for linking to that question, I couldn't find any decent information