# I can not format my ssd m.2 corrupted?

Tags: windows-10, ssd, format

the windows crashed after an update, and i was trying to install a new windows.
the windows 10 installer was not able to format the disk, tried the cmd, diskpart also didnt work, doesnt give any error tho but not formatting.

I moved the ssd to another pc. it still acting weird every time i format it comes back exactly with the same data they were in, even if i delet the data manually they come back after the format.

is this a corrupted ssd? or is this a new way prebuilt pc (acer aspire) do to protect their devices?

I tried 3rd party software, cmd from USB ... still same result

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If it walks like a duck and quacks like a duck...

Answer (score 0):

When an SSD is near end-of-life, [it becomes read-only to preserve data](https://superuser.com/questions/818952/when-an-ssd-finally-reach-its-end-of-life-can-you-still-read-its-data), if your lucky (if your *not* as lucky, it's not even readable).

What might have destroyed it is excessive write cycles, [caused by Windows 10 automatic defragmentation](https://www.pcgamer.com/windows-10-bug-wrecking-ssd/), or [caused by Windows updates](https://www.techradar.com/news/windows-10-update-could-be-damaging-your-ssd).

Microsoft may have fixed these issue by now, so a new SSD may fare better... or another OS might be more gentle to it.